# what does this $controller::Index() mean?

Tags: php, altorouter

Looking at a router I find this `$controller::Index();`, what does this mean?

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/[a:controller]/', function($controller, $action = 'index') {
    if( method_exists( $controller, $action ))
        $controller::Index();
    else
        echo 'missing';
});
```

what does this $controller::Index() mean?

Comment: What's the framework?

Comment: call `index` function of controller.

Comment: @FirstOne, altorouter

Comment: @urfusion, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$controller::Index();
```

call `index` function of controller. Where `$controller` has the name of controller class. So as per `oops` you are calling `index` function by using `scope resolution operator (::)`.